# how to place maximum value on button and alert message

Tags: ios, swift, button

I have a coffee app, where after 10 coffee points have accumulated (each coffee is worth 2 points), you receive a free coffee.

how do I make the maximum coffees ordered 10 and make an Alert Message pop up when the 10 points have been reached.

This is the View Controller for the ordering view. The error message occurs when no coffees have been ordered, but i am trying to make another Alert message pop up when the user has reached 10 points

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class OrderingViewController: UIViewController {

    var cstudent: Student = Student("name", "000")
    var totalNumberOfCoffees = 0
    var maximumNumberOfCoffee = 10

    let minimumB = 0
    let maximumA = 10

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func cappaPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        totalNumberOfCoffees += 2 
    }

    @IBAction func flatwhitePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        totalNumberOfCoffees += 2
    }

    @IBAction func mochaPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        totalNumberOfCoffees += 2
    }

    @IBAction func esspresso(_ sender: Any) {
        totalNumberOfCoffees += 2
     }


    @IBAction func placeOrderPressed(_ sender: Any) { 
    // by using this function, it makes the user know that they must order at least one 
    // coffee. if this were not here, it could waste the user's time as they 
    // may not be aware or may have made a mistake by not clicking on a coffee button.

        if totalNumberOfCoffees > 0 { // you cannot order 0 coffees
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "placeOrderSegue", sender: self)
        }
        displayAlertMessage(userMessage: "You cannot order no coffees!")

        if minimumB >= maximumA {
            totalNumberOfCoffees = maximumNumberOfCoffee
        }
        displayAlertMessage(userMessage: "FREE COFFEE")
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "placeOrderSegue"){
            let datasend = segue.destination as! AccountViewController
            datasend.currentstudent = cstudent 
            // this passes the name of the student logged in, back to the 
            // AccountViewController. This is useful as if it were not here, the 
            // name of the user would be lost.

            datasend.currentstudent.numOfCoffees += totalNumberOfCoffees 
            // add coffees bought to current student. this makes the 
            // student logged in know how many coffees they're oreder.
       }
    }

    // alert message. 
    func displayAlertMessage (userMessage: String) {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Nothing has been ordered",  message:userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil) 
        //the okAction is the button which is pressed by the users which lets them re-order on 
        // the same view controller (orderingViewController)

        myAlert.addAction(okAction)

        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Need a variable to store accumulated points?

Comment: Also, please preview the code format before post it

Comment: totalNumberOfCoffees is the var that stores points @PakHoCheung

Answer (score 1):

1. To make an Alert Message pop up when the 10 points have been reached.

Simple answer would be to create a checkReach func to check whether the totalNumberOfCoffees is above or equal to 10

```
@IBAction func cappaPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    totalNumberOfCoffees += 2 
    checkReach()
}

@IBAction func flatwhitePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    totalNumberOfCoffees += 2
    checkReach()
}

@IBAction func mochaPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    totalNumberOfCoffees += 2
    checkReach()
}

@IBAction func esspresso(_ sender: Any) {
    totalNumberOfCoffees += 2
    checkReach()
 }

func checkReach() {
    if totalNumberOfCoffees >= 10 {
        displayAlertMessage (userMessage: "REACHED")
        totalNumberOfCoffees = 10
    }
}
```